# Stretched texture with Principled texture setup

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor

So I've been trying to set up a base color image texture for my object but the image only seems to be affecting the bottom area of my object (as in image below ) and for the rest i'm getting a stretched out image. I've also tried using the node wranger setup using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>  but it still gives the same results .

Is this a glitch because I've never encountered this problem before . Does anyone have any solutions ?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shader uses UV map of the object if it is available.

If you modifiy the object mesh after the UV map has been defined (and base objects have a default UV map), then Blender can't guess where to place the UV part of new geometry or how to move the already existing one of changed parts of the mesh.

[image]

And as result,the UV map part of these new faces are flat:

[image]

So to solve it, depending on your case, you can either make the UV map again, or change the texture coordinates in the shader.

Here for instance, *"generated" texture coordinates* and the image texture changed to *"box"*:

[image]

The documentation of the *texture coordinates* node [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html).

And some practical information about it from Blender Guru [here](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-input-encyclopedia).

In case it is useful, a UV map is a map that defines the correspondence between 3D faces of the model and 2D parts of these faces on a texture.

Comment: Thanks for the help and info . It solved the problem i was facing .